# How to get authenticated Apache user using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I have a basic HTML page that is authenticated via Apache + LDAP module. I want to display the username that was entered. How do I do this using JavaScript/jQuery?

I've searched the net  but the discussions (which included discussions in the Stack Exchange network) I've seen involves a programming language like PHP/etc.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does **a basic HTML page that is authenticated via Apache + LDAP module** mean? What is that?

Comment: Some HTML pages asked for a username/password and I then enter my LDAP username/password and it lets me in.

Comment: You will need *something* server-side that outputs that information for Javascript to grab. Apache doesn't do that by default in any way AFAIK. A simple PHP/etc. script that outputs that information as JSON is probably the best idea. Your only other chance may be to configure Apache to set an HTTP response header containing the needed information; however I don't know if that's possible with standard Apache configuration directives.

Comment: If your LDAP is on different server and if u r simply posting credentials to it and getting a response of success or failure, you might also be getting username along with it. You can store that username in a cookie or browser storage and display it where ever you want in that page or across the pages.

Comment: @HarryBomrah LDAP authentication is handled internally by the web server. The client does not see any of the results.

Comment: @duskwuff well client must see at least if its a success or failure. So LDAP must be returning something to the request made for login. Otherwise simply store the username at the time of submit and can show that.